# Colored Text in a RichTextbox

Tags: vba, richtextbox

I am new to RichTextbox and I have been trying to change the font color, but couldnt find out how to do it.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can found almost everything about this [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733519(v=vs.60).aspx).